# De-serializing a JSON GET Request Response in Java

Tags: java, android, json

De-Serializing Objects within a List

I currently have an 'Admin' Entity in which upon a GET Request of AllAdmin() will return me the following response. This was used in Postman.

GET Response for AllAdmin()  [POSTMAN]

```
[
    {
        "adminId": 1,
        "fullName": "Patrick ",
        "email": "patrick@gmail.com",
        "dob": "1669-12-12",
        "mobileNumber": "96369636",
        "password": "password123!",
        "usages": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "datetimeUnlocked": "2021-06-07 10:12:23"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "datetimeUnlocked": "2021-06-07 10:12:27"
            }
        ],
        "authorization": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "datetimeAccepted": "2021-06-07 10:12:14"
            }
        ],
        "adminAllow": []
    },
    {
        "adminId": 2,
        "fullName": "Worker ",
        "email": "worker@gmail.com",
        "dob": "2000-12-12",
        "mobileNumber": "96399639",
        "password": "password123!",
        "usages": [],
        "authorization": [],
        "adminAllow": []
    } ]
```

The current code is my Admin Model in my Android Application.

Admin.java Model Class

```
public class Admin {

    @SerializedName("adminId")
    private long adminID;

    @SerializedName("fullName")
    private String adminFullName;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String adminEmail;

    @SerializedName("dob")
    private String adminDOB;

    @SerializedName("mobileNumber")
    private String adminMobileNumber;

    // Constructor
    public Admin(long adminID, String adminFullName, String adminEmail, String adminDOB, String adminMobileNumber) {
        this.adminID = adminID;
        this.adminFullName = adminFullName;
        this.adminEmail = adminEmail;
        this.adminDOB = adminDOB;
        this.adminMobileNumber = adminMobileNumber;
    }

    // Getter
    public long getAdminID() {
        return adminID;
    }

    public String getAdminFullName() {
        return adminFullName;
    }

    public String getAdminEmail() {
        return adminEmail;
    }

    public String getAdminDOB() {
        return adminDOB;
    }

    public String getAdminMobileNumber() {
        return adminMobileNumber;
    }
}
```

I would like to clarify on how I would de-serialize the **usages** and **authorization** properties so that I am able to access and manipulate the data entries for these?

I thank you in advance for your clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

For `usages`, you should use a `List<Usage>` as the serializable. My assumption is you are using Retrofit. So the Retrofit Gson converter will take care of parsing the array of `Usage`. The same logic would apply for `authorization`. You can use the different key there for the `datetimeAccepted` case.

Check this sample for `Usage`

```
public class Usage {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("datetimeUnlocked")
    @Expose
    private String datetimeUnlocked;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDatetimeUnlocked() {
        return datetimeUnlocked;
    }

    public void setDatetimeUnlocked(String datetimeUnlocked) {
         this.datetimeUnlocked = datetimeUnlocked;
    }

}
```

Your updated `Admin` class must look like this

```
public class Admin {

    @SerializedName("adminId")
    private long adminID;

    @SerializedName("fullName")
    private String adminFullName;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String adminEmail;

    @SerializedName("dob")
    private String adminDOB;

    @SerializedName("mobileNumber")
    private String adminMobileNumber;

    @SerializedName("usages")
    private List<Usage> usages;

    // Constructor
    public Admin(long adminID, String adminFullName, String adminEmail, String adminDOB, String adminMobileNumber, List<Usage> usages) {
        this.adminID = adminID;
        this.adminFullName = adminFullName;
        this.adminEmail = adminEmail;
        this.adminDOB = adminDOB;
        this.adminMobileNumber = adminMobileNumber;
        this.usages = usages;
    }

    // Getter
    public long getAdminID() {
        return adminID;
    }

    public String getAdminFullName() {
        return adminFullName;
    }

    public String getAdminEmail() {
        return adminEmail;
    }

    public String getAdminDOB() {
        return adminDOB;
    }

    public String getAdminMobileNumber() {
        return adminMobileNumber;
    }

    public List<Usage> getUsages() {
        return usages;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeromeQuah If this helped you resolve the issue. You can mark this as the accepted answer